# Shall I use com.google.common.base.Function

Tags: java

In the Guava doco, it says the Interface Function is [legacy version](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html). Shall I use that or just use the `java.util.function.Function`. And what's the difference between these two?

Comment: Use Java 8+ 's [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) instead. See also: [Package java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)

Comment: Use Guava Function only if you use Java 7 or later. In other cases, use `java.util.Function`.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally (pun intended) there is no difference between the two beyond the class hierarchy. Guava's function [extends java.util one](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/03f43227fea9c02bc7bc0fb374001f37c9d5cb43/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Function.java#L44) and doesn't implement any new behaviour nor does it define any additional methods.